# Numerical derivative of sensor data in the presence of noise

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a sensor producing [bandlimited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting) data at a predictable periodic rate, corrupted by [IID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iid) [white noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) (at least over relatively short periods of time). There is also a slowly time-varying bias, which can safely be ignored as it is several orders of magnitude smaller than the white noise.

I want to numerically differentiate the sensor data. The estimate must be [causal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system).  Wikipedia has a [nice page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) on the topic along with [filter coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients) for deterministic functions.

Is this set of coefficients good in the presence of noise, or is there a better way to perform this estimate?  What factors will the new method depend on?

Edit:

Ideally, the method will be computationally cheap as it will be run at a high rate on an embedded platform ...

Answer (score 2):

I have used the algorithm described in [this paper](http://math.lanl.gov/Research/Publications/Docs/chartrand-2010-numerical.pdf) with great success.

This method uses Tikhonov regularization of the total variation of the signal. It is parameterized, so you can easily adjust the sensitivity as needed.

Comment: So, if I understand the thrust of the paper, it's attempting to find some function that, when integrated, minimizes the difference between it and the original function (i.e. data)?

Comment: In a manner of speaking, yes. It's actually evolving a function with respect to a fictitious time variable to fit the data in such a way as to minimize the total variation.

Comment: Based on your edit, this probably will not work; it is a batch algorithm and not terribly fast.

Comment: That's more or less what I thought of the paper too. Perhaps it may work over a finite period of time (say, the last N samples), but it still missed the "cheap" remark. Apologies for not listing that criterion earlier.

Comment: @Damien I have recently encountered a technique based on the same methodology that is many times faster and should be suitable for real-time applications.

Comment: is there a reference for the application?

Comment: Yes, google "Chambolle's Algorithm" or "An Algorithm for Total Variation Minimization and Applications".

It is designed for 2D image processing, but I have it running on images about 250x250 remarkably quickly. It should be easy to adapt to the 1-D case; in fact the paper says the 1-D case is trivially easy. I intend to do some experiments with it in the next week or so; I'll post an answer if I get good results.

Comment: Emily, did you have any success with your 1D version of the filter?